# subversive not installing on eclipse kepler

Tags: android, eclipse, subversive

i want to download android google code svn repository so selected this subversive but it is not installing on my new eclipse here i am placing the error details.help me.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.1/update-site/features/org.eclipse.team.svn_1.1.0.I20130619-1700.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.1/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.help_1.1.0.I20130527-1700.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.1/update-site/features/org.eclipse.team.svn.sources_1.1.0.I20130619-1700.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried subclipse plugin for eclipse instead of subversive plugin.it is easy to use and my problem is resolved.